# ViewModel Called on Navigation Back Prism MVVM Windows Phone 8.1 C#

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, windows-phone-8.1, prism

I'm working on an application and everything works fine but when I go back to the previous page the View Model is called so it will not maintain the old data.

I use this line to call My View Model in XAML.

```
 prismmvvm:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="true"
```

So my question is:

**How do I disable the call of the View Model when I go back?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're referring **caching** here.

In the constructor of your ViewModel , set your **NavigationCacheMode**

```
this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
```

and in OnNavigatedTo event handler , check your navigationMode and delete if you're doing something more than default initializing.